# Update multiple object records dyanmically

Tags: apex

I am trying to write an Apex class that could be run on a schedule. The aim is to iterate through objects and identify NULLs on a particular field and populate that field. So far I've written the below code but it is throwing the "Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Auto_ID__c at line 16 column 56"

```
public class fixPersistentID {


List<String> objs = new List<String>{'ICP__c','Invoice_Number__c'};

        void populate_NULL_PID(){

                for(String s : objs){

                   String query = 'Select Auto_ID__c FROM '+ s +' WHERE Persistent_ID__c = null';

                   List <sObject> sObj = database.query(query);

                       for(sObject x : sObj){

                                x.Persistent_ID__c = x.Auto_ID__c;

                     }

                   update x;                                        
                }

        }

}
```

Please suggest if this is the right algorithm or do i need to approach this problem differently.

Thanks,

Comment: Why is this field not being populated by a trigger, workflow rule, process, or other synchronous automation?

Comment: Hi @DavidReed , I am already using Process Builder to populate the field when a record is created but the Process Builder does not trigger when users insert data via Import Wizard and forget to tick the "Trigger workflow rules.." so I am trying to figure a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the `put()` method on the `sObject` class to set values to generic `sObjects`. Conversely also use the `get()` method to retrieve values.

So something like this:

```
sObject[] sObjList = Database.query('Select CustomField__c From CustomObject__c');

System.debug(sObjList[0].get('CustomField__c'));

sObject sObj = new sObject();
sObj.put('Custom_Field__c',value);
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm